# To build java SpringMVC4 web framework what jar is need?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have to do new web project and I decided to use Spring MVC latest version 4. My question is Spring MVC 4 is stable version, if yes what jar do I need to collect. I also dont want to use maven and I need pure jar file.

Thanks for your help and time.
Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I already found..
Spring MVC annotation jar

aopalliance-1.0.jar

commons-logging-1.2.jar

javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar (download)

jstl-1.2.jar (download)

spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar

spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar

spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar

spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar

spring-expression-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar

spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar

spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Spring is already on version 4.3.x, you can use 4.2.2 if you want but you'll be missing some things. And you should really learn and use Maven (or Gradle) if you are working with Spring.